# Updating multiple local notifications with SQL

Tags: android, sql, alarmmanager, android-notifications, local

Hello currently I have setup a application which allows the user to set an alarm. When this alarms reaches it designated time it will then send a notification to the user. Now currently each time this notification is activated it sends a static message e.g. "You have a notification". I want to be able to change this notifications title to the alarms name which I have stored inside of SQLOPENHELPER when the user made the alarm.

I have also given each alarm a specific ID which is the current time in milliseconds and then also stored this inside of my SQL. Now I know you require a new ID for each notification but how would I do this and relate it back to my SQL?

I have included a small diagram just to clarify what I'm doing and my current alarm and broadcast receiver...

Diagram................

[image]

Set alarm.....

// id - relates to the custom id given to that alarm
// receiver - is our intent

```
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(), id,  receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

// Intent array list is used to store multiple alarms

```
 intentArrayList.add(pendingIntent);
```

Broadcast receiver...

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



    Intent moveActivity = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);


    moveActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    // Works with moveActivity to move the user back to main application.
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, moveActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)

            .setAutoCancel(true);


    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

// Notification ID has been left at 0 because I don't know what to do as this point and after trying to figure it out for 2 days I thought I should ask.

//// UPDATE
Main Activity

I have implemented a put extra just under my intent Array List

```
   receiver.putExtra("title", id);
```

Broadcast

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {

        pass = bundle.getString("title");

 //I have put my notification in this section


 }
```

I tested it by putting "pass" which is the String for retrieving the put extra into the title of my notification and it comes up blank?

Comment: pass the rowid of your added sqlite row entry

Comment: I also had that idea but what if you have lets say 5 alarms set and you simply pass the SQL row id then you're only going to get the first row each time. Also thank you for your time

Comment: sorry i dont get you, if you pass the id in the intent you will read the row you need

Comment: Ok when the alarm activates it just goes to the broadcast receiver and sends off the notification. I need it so that when this goes to the broadcast receiver its sends the next id in my list this way it doesn't just keep repeating the same rows information for each alarm. Does this help?

Comment: you are calling `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(), id,  receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)`, where `receiver` is an intent to your broadcast receiver, then pass the rowid in that intent so you can read your db based on that

Comment: I'm kinda with you, do you have a example as I want to get my head around this?

Comment: example of passing the `long` extra to the `intent`?

Comment: Yeah I guess, I'm still a little unsure as to how this is all going to marry up. For example I set 5 alarms all on different days and hours, my phone is happy to send static notifications for all of them at there correct times. But how is receiver (intent) going to know which ID to send to the notification or is it going to send the same ID over and over again which means you will get the same row back from the SQL each time?

Comment: then simply call `Intent#putExtra(String name, long value)`

Comment: How would it know which ID to grab?

Comment: the one you got from `SQLiteDatabase#insert` method call

Comment: Please look at my update

Comment: @pskink I fixed my issue and you were right putExtra was the correct route. If you want to put that as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Update your receiver intent as below to pass the `ALARM_ID`:

   ```
   Intent receiver = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Receiver.class);
   receiver.putExtra("KEY_ALARM_ID", ALARM_ID); // ALARM_ID = id
   ```
2. In `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`, Use `ALARM_ID` as `requestCode`.

   ```
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, ALARM_ID, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
   ```

> Always use different `requestCode` for different notification to get
>   correct result.

3. In `notify()` method, use `ALARM_ID` as `id`:

   ```
   notificationManager.notify(ALARM_ID, builder.build());
   ```

> Notification `id` should be unique within your application. If a
>   notification with the same `id` has already been posted by your
>   application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the
>   updated information.

4. In your BroadcastReceiver class `onReceive()` method get the `ALARM_ID`:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
   {

       int alarmId= intent.getExtras().getInt("KEY_ALARM_ID");

       // Do something with alarmId
   }
   ```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I did, but is very useful for anyone else who might have this issue.

Comment: Glad to know that... :)

Comment: @Steven if my answer seems useful please give an up vote. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

// Main activity

```
 receiver.putExtra("title", id);
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(), id,  receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

 intentArrayList.add(pendingIntent);
```

Broadcast

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

int pass = bundle.getInt("title" , 1);
```

Thanks psKink you gave me the kick I needed